# Firebase for Unity, missing SynchronizationContextBehaviour

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am currently working on an IOS and Android project with Unity 2022.3.4f1 and using Firebase Auth, Realtime Database, Analytics and Crashlytics in that project.
I just imported all four packages from the SDK **version 11.2 (the latest available version)**. But it seems I am missing a script called: **SynchronizationContextBehaviour**.

When I press play, I get this warning message:
[image: Missing script warning error]

And since the warning comes from a loaded resource, I checked all of the GameObjects in the **DoNotDestroyOnLoad** part of the hierarchy and the GameObjecct **Firebase Services** is missing a script called **SynchronizationContextBehaviour**.
You can find the proof below in the normal and debug mode of the inspector:
[image: Missing script in the normal mode of the inspector]
[image: Missing script in the debug mode of the inspector]

So why is this script missing and how can I get it in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, how did this particular GameObject (Firebase Services) and component get into your project? It is not part of the [Firebase Unity SDK](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Afirebase%2Ffirebase-unity-sdk%20SynchronizationContextBehaviour&type=code) nor is it in the [Firebase for Unity API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/s/results?q=SynchronizationContextBehaviour).

Check your project's revision history to determine where they may have been introduced and removed and by whom.